Using the binomial formula in the form $(k - k)^n$
While proving a certain property of the number theoretic mobius function, namely that it is invertible in the monoid of multiplicative functions and its inverse is the constant function $\eta\left(n\right) = 1$,

I used an argument which boils down to an expression of the form
$$
\sum_{j = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{j}(-1)^{j}
$$
which I then claim is equal
to $\underline{zero}$ since this is a special case of the Binomial Theorem
$$
\left(x + y\right)^{n}\quad \mbox{when}\quad
x = 1\ \mbox{and}\ y = -1
$$
and hence
$\left(x + y\right){^n} = \left(1 - 1\right)^{n} = 0$.

This is kosher right? Nothing prevents me from using the binomial theorem under these conditions?

Absolutely.  Good argument.  For a combinatorial proof of the same identity, see this question

This is also the observation that the sum of the entries (alternating the signs) in any row of Pascal's triangle (except the 0th row) is 0.

$$
\sum_{j = 0}^{n}{n \choose j} \left(-1\right)^{j} = \color{red}{\Large\delta_{n0}}
$$

Yes, in this case, it works. You can expand $(1-1)^n$ to verify and get $\sum^n_{j=0} (-1)^j \binom{n}{j}$ is equal to $(1-1)^n$.
